# Monitor exchange 2010 archiving

Tags: email, monitoring, exchange-2010

Would like some advice on an exchange 2010 query.

We would like to be able to monitor the archiving activity of our new exchange 2010 ecosystem. As far as i'm aware, there is no formal tool with which to monitor how and when 2010 archives users' e-mails.

We currently have everyone using the same default 3 month archiving policy, but we can't tell if this is done on a daily basis, weekly basis or what have you, nor do we know at what time in the day the archiving process takes place.

Can anyone offer any advice on a way we can monitor this, or, failing that, set the default time at which it should run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Message Records Management in Exchange 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd297955.aspx). You can set certain retention policies to meet your specific needs.